# How to modify Media Library images DPI [ image quality down to make small in size ]

Tags: post-thumbnails, media-library, images

I wonder if there any code or hook out there to manage the image DPI, for example when we use photoshop or other image editing software we use export and image quality to 0-100%, now i am looking for a plugin or code to define the media library'r image DPI to make them small in size.

This is i want store two version one with smaller size[DPI] and one for HD quality.

Anyone Can help ?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic per the [FAQ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DPI (as saved in image metadata) does not really apply to displays since pixel density is property of hardware.

You can fake this by resizing image with smaller dimensions in HTML, but saving with higher JPEG compression might make more sense.

Default compression level WP uses is `90` (out of 100) and it can be modified by filters:

- `jpeg_quality` (this seems to be legacy one)
- `wp_editor_set_quality` (in new `WP_Image_editor` class)